# Making the entries of a matrix positive

Tags: linear-algebra, algebraic-combinatorics

I am considering two slightly more relaxed version of the question asked here: https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/119034/making-the-entries-of-a-matrix-positive

The two questions are:

**Question 1:**

Consider a matrix $M\in\mathbb{R}^{m\times n}$. When does there exist either a matrix $P_M \in \mathbb{R}^{m\times m}$ such that
$$
P_M M = \text{abs}(M)
$$
or a matrix $Q_M  \in \mathbb{R}^{n\times n} $ such that
$$
M Q_M = \text{abs}(M).
$$
If these matrices exist, how would we compute them?

**NOTE** : by $\text{abs}(M)$ we mean the matrix formed by taking the entry wise absolute value of $M$.

**Question 2**:

Again, consider a matrix $M\in\mathbb{R}^{m\times n}$. Then by $\text{sgn}(M)$ denote the sign pattern matrix of $M$, that is,
$$ [\text{sgn}(M)](i,j) :=
\begin{cases}
-1 & \text{if} M(i,j) < 0,\\
1 & \text{if} M(i,j) > 0,\\
0 & \text{if} M(i,j) = 0,\\
\end{cases}
\ \ \ \forall\ 1\leq i\leq n, 1\leq j\leq m.  
$$

When does there exist either a matrix $P_M \in \mathbb{R}^{m\times m}$ such that
$$
P_M M = \text{sgn}(M)
$$
or a matrix $Q_M  \in \mathbb{R}^{n\times n} $ such that
$$
M Q_M = \text{sgn}(M).
$$
These matrices do not necessarily need to be invertible.

**NOTE** : None of the matrices are necessarily invertible.

***EDIT*** : I should note, it would be very nice if a method exists that does not require $\text{abs}(M)$ or $\text{sgn}(M)$ to be computed